# Python: Prioritizing tasks and Running asynchronous tasks without a lock

Tags: asynchronous, gevent, greenlets

Right now I'm using Gevent, and I wanted to ask two questions:

- Is there a way to execute specific tasks that will **never execute asynchronously** (instead of using a Lock in each of these tasks)
- Is there's a way to **prioritize** spawned tasks in Gevent? Like a group of tasks that will be generated with low priority that will be executed when all of the other tasks are done. **For example**, two tasks that listen to different socket when each of these tasks handles the socket requests in various priority

If it's not possible in Gevent, is there any other library that it can be done?

***Edit***
Maybe Celery can help me here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage computing resources, Python async libraries can't help here, because, AFAIK, neither has priority scheduler. All greenthreads are equal.

Task queues generally have a notion of priority, so Celery or Beanstalk is one way to do it.

If your problem does not require task (re)execution guarantees, persistence, multi-machine work distribution, then I would just start few worker processes, assign them CPU, IO, disk priorities using OS and send work/results via UNIX socket DGRAM. Kind of ad-hoc simpler version of task queue. If you go this way, please share your work as open source project, I believe there's demand for this kind of solution.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll make some open source project in the weekend that solves my problems.. But in the meantime I will just use Gevent with locks and put all the low priority tasks in a different low priority process